# RabbitMQ pub sub with Kubeflow pipeline trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, rabbitmq, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am trying to implement a RabbitMQ subscriber that will trigger a pipeline in Kubeflow. If I create a fanout exchange then if there is no subscriber the messages will be discarded. So if a subscriber joins later he will not get the messages he wants to work on.

The solution is pretty simple of course.

- Launce RabbitMQ instance with a fanout exchange X.
- Run an application that connects to a queue Q that is bound to exchange X.
- Once any event E is published to the exchange X, the subscriber application picks it up and calls the REST API of the Kubeflow to trigger a pipeline.

The problem is for this pattern I need to have an application running all the time.

- Is there any way that KubeFlow directly pulls the queue item from the RabbitMQ?

Note:

1. I can publish the message to a specific queue for sure, but then there will be a single consumer. It won't be a pub-sub.
2. I am using AmazonMQ. I am aware it's possible to deploy SAM that will poll for new items every 200ms and invoke a Lambda function. This SAM is still an application that runs all the time. This is I want to avoid